# MacOS In-App Purchases

Tags: macos, in-app-purchase

I cannot find the documentation regarding the code to do In-App purchases for MacOS Apps (not iOS). The official link (https://developer.apple.com/appstore/mac/resources/in-app-purchase/) does not say anything about the coding part of the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and this [Technical Note](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html): they cover both platforms (MacOS and iOS) and gives sample code.